# Phrase for "what's up" but using numerical code

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, slang

Some time ago I've heard phrase

> What's the 599?

Where "599" is some three-digit number I don't remember, which one and why it is used. Maybe it was 322.

The meaning of the phrase is "How it is going" or "what's the situation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number you are looking for is "411", pronounced as separate digits, "four-one-one". It means accurate or insightful information. It implies a desire for clear, correct, concise and relevant information, and might be used, for instance, if you are called somewhere urgently and want to know what's going on. It might also be used when asking about another person, or a situation - "what's the 411 on Joe Bloggs?"

It comes from the phone number used in America for what we in the UK call "directory enquiries" - the number you phone to try and find a phone number.